# Share screen as webcam?

Tags: video, webcam, streaming, video-streaming

Does anyone know of a program or method to share my screen and system audio as a webcam device?

I'm currently using [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) for streaming which works great but I don't see any option to do what I'm looking for out of the box.